# Recursive function throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, function, recursion

I get the error java.lang.StackOverflowError when I try to run my code:

```
public class calc {
    public static void main(String[] args){
double zahl = 847362;
System.out.println( wannawoerk(zahl) );

}


public static double wannawoerk(double zahl){
    if (zahl == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return wannawoerk(zahl - 1) + zahl;
} }
```

Is there any workaround for this problem? I have to use a recursive function without for, while, etc.

Comment: Why `double`? The problem here is either A) The stack can't go 847,361 frames deep (think about it, that's a lot), or B) IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point fun and games. I suspect (A), but...

Comment: "Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're required to use recursion, you could increase memory available for stack: `java -Xss256m YourClass` - sets stack to 256MB max.

In real world, you'd most probably use a `while` loop for this. Or, in this case, compute it right away (you don't need recursion for the thing you are computing), but I guess that's not the point.

Comment: @Bathsheba You're right. I didn't bother to verify it as IMO it is secondary and not to the point of question. But I see having wrong formula in the answer is not a good idea and could mislead someone, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jiri.

Answer (score 9):

Repeated subtraction of 1 from `zahl` *will* eventually give you 1. (Floating point subtraction by an integer on integers in this range **is** exact: you'd only get oddities above the 53rd power of 2).

Your problem is that your JVM is probably not going to allow you that many recursive calls.

A stack depth approaching one million is really not going to end well!

Comment: For mentioning that integers up to 2^^54 are represented without error. +1 64-bit float has a 53-bit mantissa as the top bit is always 1 for normalised number only the bottom 52 bits need to be stored.  2^^54 is the last ok integer as it's a power of two but 2^^54+1 can't be represented.

Comment: Hum. We'll meet in the middle. I think the first number that can't be represented is 2^^53 + 1

Answer (score 1):

The stack is not unlimited and Java doesn't have tail call optimisation. The simplest solution is to have the method

```
return zahl * (zahl + 1) / 2;
```

Ideally you wouldn't use double instead you would write

```
public static long sumUpTo(int n) {
    return n * (n + 1L) / 2;
}
```

To make any sane optimisation you need a more realistic method.

Comment: Upvoted. 1) for the tail call snippet and, 2) for taking the time to write out the closed form solution.

Comment: But there is no recursion.

Comment: @HansMüller indeed. Recursion is rarely a good idea in Java esp when the level of recursion is order N of an input. Order log N is okay such as for balanced binary trees.

Answer (score 0):

This example of yours is very also illustrated in [*this comment!*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35351814/2136815) along with a few other very detailed explanations of this issue, why it happens and how to handle it.

Comment: I did consider it, but since the general question and explanation was different and only one of the answers provided in the link was similar I wasn't too sure about it. So simply not to ruin anything, I would leave that decision to someone more competent in that matter than myself